# Select last n chars from a string in EF Core using HasComputedColumnSql() Method

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 5.
Given is the following class

```
public class Account
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Iban { get; set; }
   public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The default value of AccountNumber is equal to last ten digits of iban.
Based on [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#computed-columns) documentation I tried to calculate its default value by using the HasComputedColumnSql() method like this:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
                .Property(x => x.AccountNumber)
                .HasComputedColumnSql("RIGHT([Iban], 10)");
```

but I do get the following error when updating the database:
"Incorrect syntax near 'IBAN, 10'."
What is the correct way to use the SQL RIGHT() method in HasComputedColumnSql() method?

**UPDATE**: EF Core LogFile:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
DECLARE @var0 sysname;
SELECT @var0 = [d].[name]
FROM [sys].[default_constraints] [d]
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] [c] ON [d].[parent_column_id] = [c].[column_id] AND [d].[parent_object_id] = [c].[object_id]
WHERE ([d].[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[Account]') AND [c].[name] = N'AccountNumber');
IF @var0 IS NOT NULL EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [Account] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var0 + '];');
ALTER TABLE [Account] DROP COLUMN [AccountNumber];
ALTER TABLE [Account] ADD [AccountNumber] AS RIGHT[IBAN, 10];
```

**Update:** My latest migration is the following:

```
public partial class V10 : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "AccountNumber",
                table: "Account",
                type: "nvarchar(max)",
                nullable: true,
                defaultValue: "IBAN",
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldType: "nvarchar(max)",
                oldNullable: true,
                oldComputedColumnSql: "RIGHT(Iban,10)");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "AccountNumber",
                table: "Account",
                type: "nvarchar(max)",
                nullable: true,
                computedColumnSql: "RIGHT(Iban,10)",
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldType: "nvarchar(max)",
                oldNullable: true,
                oldDefaultValue: "IBAN");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample values ? Do you have any other log for this.

Comment: @dotnetstep I have updated my post

Comment: @dotnetstep if we have Iban = "AT791937011111111111" the AccountNumber should be equal to: "1111111111"

Comment: @JonathanLarouche That is log part so It is generated by EF Core that is what I believe.

Comment: it seems model you provided is not correct. You mention AccountNumber as integer and value you specified alphanumeric.

Comment: @dotnetstep Sorry that was my mistake. Both AccountNumber and Iban are string

Comment: Have you tried not to put the square brakets over the IBAN columnName: `RIGHT(Iban, 10)` ?

Comment: @JonathanLarouche yes.  I even removed the space between "," and 10. Thought that might cause the problem but that also didn't help

Comment: @brk Are you sure about HasComputedColumn is correct over here. The way it is being display it looks like you might have done RIGHT([Ibn,10]) instead of RIGHT([ibn],10)

Comment: @dotnetstep yes. This is after the update: 
 modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
                .Property(x => x.AccountNumber)
                .HasComputedColumnSql("RIGHT(Iban,10)");

Comment: @dotnetstep new update: I replaced the HasComputedColumnSql() method with HasDefaultValue() and again got the same error as above. Do you know why? Can it be because of Cache or something?

Comment: @brk I tried my self with above stuff and it is working fine. I am sure that you have generated migration for this. If you put some code from that migration what it added over there then I can help you out.

Comment: @dotnetstep I have updated my post again. This is the latest migration that I did. As I mentioned earlier I replaced the HasComputedColumnSql() with HasDefaultValue() to see if this one works, but still got the same error.

Comment: @Brk HasDefaultValue will give you computed column. So you have to use Computed column that is for sure. I have used .NET 5 and EF core 5.0.15 version. Are you using which specific version ?

Comment: @dotnetstep I am using .NET Core 3.1 with EF Core V 5.0.10